# Need help on understanding awk command to combine two files

Tags: awk

I am trying to compare two files based on the common columns($2 in 1st file and $4 in 2nd file) and print the matched records from both files, but the problem with the awk that i am using is, it is printing only the records from the second  file.

Can any one please provide the solution for this?
file1

```
111,abc
222,abc
111,bcd
```

file2

```
1,123,345,abc
2,234,232,bcd
2,hhh,343,bcd
```

desired output:

```
111,abc,1,123,345,abc
222,abc,1,123,345,abc
111,bcd,2,234,232,bcd
111,bcd,2,hhh,343,bcd
```

with the below awk command i got ouput like this

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$2];next } (($4) in a) {print $0","a[$1]}' file file2
1,123,345,abc,
2,234,232,bcd,
2,hhh,343,bcd,
```

not getitng any value at the a[$1] in the output.

Comment: can you make your title more descriptive? and can you properly format your code?

Comment: Probably `awk` is not the best tool here, you can try with `join`. Also, note your logic on matching lines is a bit blur, because you want to print everything matching 4th column on file1, so that it is best to store firstly file2 and then loop through file1 printing the desired values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start off by saying that you will never get that output with the approach you have started. Not to forget the corrections that Ed suggested in his post, but you are using column which is repetitive as keys. When you do that the initial value held by that key gets lost and replaced by the recently seen value.

To achieve that output, what you should do is create a composite keys which will be unique. Here is how I would have done it:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }          # Set your input and output separator in BEGIN block
NR==FNR { line[$0]; next }        # Load the entire line as key as columns can repeat
{
    for (key in line) {           # Iterate through your array
        split (key, arry, /,/);   # Split your key on "," and store in an array
        if (arry[2] == $4) {      # If that key is matching your column 4
            print key, $0         # Print the entire key long with entire line from file2
        }
    }
}' file1 file2
111,abc,1,123,345,abc
222,abc,1,123,345,abc
111,bcd,2,234,232,bcd
111,bcd,2,hhh,343,bcd
```

Comment: +1 for the solution but if the OP can't figure out whether to use `$1` or `$4` to access the array contents (and that they can't BOTH be correct) then I'm not sure what they'll get out of it even with all the nice commenting! Hopefully they'll ask questions...

Comment: @EdMorton Thats where I shall point them to you and run away in to the oblivion. `:P`

Comment: Thank you Jaypal. But my question is why i am not able to print the columns from the file with this awk statement awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$2];next } (($4) in a) {print $0","a[$1]}' file file2. what's wrong with this statement?

Comment: @unixuser During the processing of second file when you use column1 as your key to print the array you should be using column4 instead. Look at the matching columns from both files. You will only get the values printed when you use the right keys to reference them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `FS` and `OFS` variables to tell awk your fields are comma-separated (see the awk man page), and you are populating `a[]` using the 2nd field from file1 (e.g. `abc`) as it's indices, then when testing it you're using $4 from files (e.g. `abc` again) which seems reasonable but then when printing you're trying to access its contents using the 1st field from file2 (e.g. `1`) as it's indices instead. Think about that.

Comment: Hi, added a field seperator (,) in the awk statement. can you please check now?

Comment: Fix the other stuff too then I'll check.